# The id and class attributes don't work

Tags: html, css, class, attributes

I'm trying to make a HTML-code but when I try to use 'div' with a class or id it won't do what's written in the class. Only when I write it between the tag (so the when I write width between the tag it works, but not if I wrote it in the class).

```css
.header {
  width: 100px;
  height: 10px;
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <link type="text/css" rel="OIM11 - CSS" href="OIM11 - CSS.css" />
  <title></title>
</head>

<body style="background-color:#666666">
  <div class="header"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Any idea why this doesn't work?

Comment: rel should be set to `stylesheet` in the header, _The required rel attribute specifies the relationship between the current document and the linked document/resource._

Comment: Converted to snippet, seems to work just fine. You're just linking the stylesheet all wrong.

Comment: It seems to be working fine, I cant see the problem.

Comment: The snippet engine does not use that link tag. It works, because it is coded to include the css correctly. @SergChernata

Answer (score 1):

When in doubt, open developer tools on literally any website and look at the way they include stylesheets. I don't know how you came up with that format. This is the proper way:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="path/to/main.css">
```

Also, avoid spaces when naming files. In your shoes, I would rename the current file to `OIM11-CSS.css`.

Comment: Yes i agree with Serg, its best practice to use developer tools to see how style sheets are loaded in web browser for a HTML page. I use most of the time FireBug to debug my style sheets and even use firebug to compute the element's style attributes.